# How do I create systemd service unit configuration file for MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, systemd

> **Update**
>   I was able to create the mysqld.service file thanks to using /etc/systemd/system exist as suggested by Robert Longson
>
> Now my problem has changed. When I start the service it fails. I ran `systemctl status mysqld.service` and here is the output:
>
> ```
>    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-03-29 19:01:25 CDT; 38s ago
>      Docs: man:mysqld(7)
>            http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
>   Process: 9251 ExecStart=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --daemonize --pid
> mysqld.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
> mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
> Stopped MySQL Server.
> mysqld.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
> mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> mysqld.service: Failedto start MySQL Server
> ```

I am trying to start MySQL Server 5.7, using systemd, for the first time after installing it. The manual says to create a configuration file in /usr/lib/systemd/system **but that sub-directory doesn't exist** (I am on Ubuntu 18.04). I am following this guide:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-post-install.html#secure-deployment-systemd-startup

> To configure the MySQL installation to work with systemd:
>
> 1. Add a systemd service unit configuration file with details about the MySQL service. The file is named mysqld.service and is placed in /usr/lib/systemd/system.

```
shell> cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
shell> touch mysqld.service
shell> chmod 644 mysqld.service
```

Since I don't have the 'system' sub-directory of systemd, I just created the mysql.service file **directly** in /usr/lib/systemd.
After following the rest of the instructions, I got to:

```
shell> systemctl start mysqld
```

but it failed with:

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file mysqld.service does not exist.
```

Would someone please explain what I have done wrong? Thank you.

Comment: does /etc/systemd/system exist? If so use that instead.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that seems to have worked, because it allowed me to do ```systemctl enable mysqld.service``` which created the symlink. Now my problem has changed. When I start the service it fails. I ran systemctl status mysqld.service which says it automatically restarted and then failed because ```Start request repeated too quickly. ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service files are actually in /etc/systemd/system rather than /usr/lib/systemd/system

If you want to find out why your service is failing you can either try `systemctl status mysqld` or for a more complete log look into the journalctl command e.g. `journalctl -u mysqld -S today`.

Comment: Thanks again, Robert. Running ```journalctl -u mysqld -S today``` helped show me that my mysqld.service file was not pointing to the correct location of mysqld in the ExecStart line, so it couldn't start it.